# Jackson and GSON unusable with Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, reflection, jackson, gson

I've been searching to find an answer/workaround for this issue for some time now.

The problem is when converting a Json String into a Java Object, an Exception is thrown along the lines of "Reflection is not allowed on private java.lang.Throwable java.lang.Throwable.cause".

I understand that GAE is a sandboxed envrionment so I am unable to push the boundaries as much as I would like however, I am keen to not have to resort to writing my own deserializer.

The reason being the data types I am working with are quite complex, so writing my own deserializer would not only be time consuming, but would defeat the point of using frameworks such as Jackson and GSON.

Below is the code sample for both Jackson and GSON, both implementations work locally (not sanboxed) and not when deploying to GAE.
Jackson:

```
public class JsonConverterJackson {

    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.NON_PRIVATE);

    /** This method deserializes the specified Json into an object of the specified class.
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws JsonMappingException 
     * @throws JsonParseException 
     *
     */
    public static <T> T convertFromJson(String toConvert, Class<T> clazz) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException{
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        return mapper.readValue(toConvert, clazz);
    }


    /**
     * This method serializes the specified object into its equivalent Json representation.
     * @throws JsonProcessingException 
     */
    public static String convertToJson(Object toConvert) throws JsonProcessingException{
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(toConvert);
    }
```

GSON:

```
public class JsonConverter {
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").create();
//private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.PRIVATE).setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").create();

/** This method deserializes the specified Json into an object of the specified class.
 *
 */
public static <T> T convertFromJson(String toConvert, Class<T> clazz){
    return gson.fromJson(toConvert, clazz);
}

/**
 * This method serializes the specified object into its equivalent Json representation.
 */
public static String convertToJson(Object toConvert){
    return gson.toJson(toConvert);
}
```

Exception details for Jackson:
Here is the Exception logs for Jackson:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not access private java.lang.Throwable java.lang.Throwable.cause (from class java.lang.Throwable; failed to set access: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Reflection is not allowed on private java.lang.Throwable java.lang.Throwable.cause

Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not access private java.lang.Throwable java.lang.Throwable.cause (from class java.lang.Throwable; failed to set access: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Reflection is not allowed on private java.lang.Throwable java.lang.Throwable.cause
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:272)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:247)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:146)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findContextualValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:
```

Any suggestions would be most welcoming.

Comment: Please post the exact exception and its stack trace.

Comment: That error message is odd .. from what I can tell it says "can't write to the private field `cause` of `Throwable`". Do you have a `Throwable/Exception` field in the POJO by accident?

Comment: Are you trying to serialize a `Throwable`? Why?

Comment: One of the Objects returned in my POJO is actually a Custom Exception. Do you think this could cause the issue? This Field is null in all cases unless an exception is returned in the Json String from the third party source.

Comment: Maybe my comment above explains the reason why I would face an issue here. If that is the case, it would mean that you are able to serialize Throwable, just not on GAE.

Comment: Ran into this problem too on Google App Engine; simply wanted to marshall some error response json into a subclassed IOException and throw it up the stack. The solution for me was to unmarshall to a pojo and put the pojo into the subclassed IOException, instead of unmarshalling directly to the Exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the Custom Exception field from the POJO did the trick.
Serializing to a Throwable seems to be a limitation using the GAE Security Manager.
You are unable to access private fields of any Objects other than your own.